# Connect Matlab to Sql server

Tags: matlab, sql-server-2012

I want to connect `Matlab` to `Sql server`.

this is my code:

```
db = database('ChifcoProd-2013-12-12-11-37', '', '', 'sqljdbc4.jar',...
'jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=ChifcoProd-2013-12-12-11-37')
```

error:

```
JDBC Driver Error: sqljdbc4.jar. Driver Not Found/Loaded
```

the driver is already installed and I added the path to javaclasspath but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Help within MatLab, its very helpful.

You are using the correct database connection:

```
conn = database(instance,username,password,driver,databaseurl)
```

The example provided by MatLab looks like this:
Connect to an Oracle database via JDBC driver.

Connect to the database, test_db, using the user name, scott, and password, tiger. Use the JDBC driver, oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, to make the connection. The URL defined by the driver vendor is jdbc:oracle:oci7:

```
conn = database('test_db','scott','tiger',...
          'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:oci7:')
```

OR

Microsoft SQL Server Authenticated Database Connection

Connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database with integrated Windows Authentication using a JDBC driver.

Close MATLAB if it is running.

Insert the path to the database driver JAR file in the classpath.txt file. The classpath.txt file is located at:

```
$MATLABROOT\toolbox\local\classpath.txt
```

The updated path entry should now include the full path to the driver. For example:

```
C:\DB_Drivers\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar
```

Insert the path to the folder containing sqljdbc_auth.dll in the librarypath.txt file. The librarypath.txt file is located at:

```
$MATLABROOT\toolbox\local\librarypath.txt
```

The path entry should not include the file name sqljdbc_auth.dll:

```
C:\DB_Drivers\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\auth\x64
```

The sqljdbc_auth.dll file is installed in the following location:

```
<installation>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\auth\<arch>
```

where  is the installation directory of the SQL server driver.

- If you are running a 32-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM), then use the
  sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the x86 folder, even if the operating system
  is the x64 version.
- If you are running a 64-bit JVM on a x64 processor, then use the
  sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the x64 folder.
- If you are running a 64-bit JVM on a IA-64 processor, then use the
  sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the IA64 folder.

Start MATLAB.

Use the AuthType parameter to establish a Windows Authentication connection.

```
conn = database('dbName','','', ...
   'Vendor','Microsoft SQL Server','Server','servername',...
   'AuthType','Windows')
```