# Matlab is unable to find JDBC driver to connect to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, matlab, jdbc

I want to connect Matlab to Microsoft SQL Server.

To make the connection I use the following code in Matlab:

```
conn = database('database_name', '', '', 'Vendor', 'Microsoft SQL     Server', 'Server', 'localhost', 'AuthType', 'Windows', 'PortNumber',1433)
```

I get the following error:

> 'Unable to find JDBC driver.'

I installed the JDBC driver, using [this help-page](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-windows.html). However, I will get the same error message.  What can I do to make a connection?

Btw, I found [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469973/connect-matlab-to-sql-server). However I cannot change the classpath.txt file and the librarypath.txt file as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. 
I had to run the following command before I make a connection:

```
javaaddpath 'C:\location of\sqljdbc4.jar';
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all do not forget to start up MySQL from xampp then
excute this command in command window
`cd(prefdir);`
`edit javaclasspath.txt`
now just write the path to the connector-bin.jar u downloaded and do not forget to add .jar
restart matlab .
note : only connector J version 5 work for matlab 2017 not version 8.